# AgGrid's cellRendererFramework doesn't have access to Material UI's theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ag-grid

I have a `AgGrid` which by using `cellRendererFramework` i can render my own buttons in a column, everything works great, i am able to render my material UI button without any problem that is until i created more colors in my theme palette like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    text: {
      primary: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
      secondary: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
    },
    primary: {
      main: '#064d80',
      contrastText: 'white',
    },
    // secondary: {
    //   main: '#f44336',
    // },
    secondary: {
      main: '#1b5e20',
      contrastText: 'white',
    },
    success: {
      main: '#28a745',
      contrastText: 'white',
      dark: 'rgb(97, 0, 0)'
    },
    pdfRed: {
      main: '#880000',
      contrastText: 'white',
      dark: 'rgb(97, 0, 0)'
    },
    lightGreen: {
      main: 'rgb(92, 184, 92)',
      contrastText: 'white',
      dark: 'rgb(45, 92, 46)',
    },
  },
});

function App() {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">

        <Cockpit />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And then i wrote a button class which uses the palette :

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MaterialUIButton from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const Button = withStyles(theme => {
    console.log('theme', theme)
    return {
        root: props =>
            (props.variant === "contained" && props.color !== 'primary' && props.color !== 'secondary')
                ? {
                    color: theme.palette[props.color].contrastText,
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].main,
                    "&:hover": {
                        backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].dark,
                        // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
                        "@media (hover: none)": {
                            backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].main
                        }
                    }
                }
                : {}
    }
}
)(MaterialUIButton);

const muiButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <Button {...props}>
            {props.children}
        </Button>
    )
}

export default muiButton;
```

This works great anywhere else in my program but when i use the button inside the `cellRendererFramework` i get an error that the color i am accessing is `undefined`, after i did `console.log(theme)`, i noticed that inside `cellRendererFramework` the `theme.palette`, does not have the new colors i had provided to my program in `app.js`, whats the issue, what do you suggest as a workaround ?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you fix this problem? If so can you please share the solution

Comment: @Paul I posted a workaround which i used to get the job done. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this problem which i'm going to share here.
Instead of relying on `withStyle theme`, i import my color palette which contains all my colors after that, inside my `Button` component, i will do something like this:

```
import { colorPalette } from 'colorPalette';

//...
contrastText = colorPalette[color].contrastText
main = colorPalette[color].main
dark = colorPalette[color].dark
```

Meaning i look for the color inside the color palette which means that it can always be found.
The usage is pretty simple as well, i do something like this:

```
<Button color={'success'} />
<Button color={'pdfRed'} />
```

Comment: At least a workaround. Still hope that ag-grid will soon correct this itself. Already an ag-grid ticket: AG-4177